# Multiple To clauses in Data step

Tags: sas

I have a data step where I have a few columns that need tied to one other column.

I have tried using multiple "from" statements and " to" statements and a couple other permutations of that, but nothing seems to do the trick. The code looks something like this:

```
data analyze;
set css_email_analysis;
from = bill_account_number;
to = customer_number;
output;
from = bill_account_number;
to = email_addr;
output;
from = bill_account_number;
to = e_customer_nm;
output;
run;
```

I would like to see two columns showing bill accounts in the "from" column, and the other values in the "to", but instead I get a bill account and its customer number, with some "..."'s for the other values.

Comment: I think you need to add some sample data, to show what you have as input and what you expect as output. It does not need to be real data, but it should reflect your situation as closely as possible. [ask]

Comment: You don't have any 'to clauses' in your program. You have three assignment statement to a variable named `to`.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

This is most likely because SAS has two datatypes and the first time the `to` variable is set up, it has the value of `customer_number`. At your second `to` statement you attempt to set `to` to have the value of `email_addr`. Assuming `email_addr` is a character variable, two things can happen here:

- Customer_number is a number - `to` has already been set up as a number, so SAS cannot force `to` to become a character, an error like this may appear:

> NOTE: Invalid numeric data, 'me@mywebsite.com' , at line 15 column 8. to=.
>   *ERROR*=1 *N*=1

- Customer_number is a character - `to` has been set up as a character, but without explicitly defining its length, if it happens to be shorter than the value of `email_addr` then the email address will be truncated. SAS will not show an error if this happens:

Code:

```
data _NULL_;
  to = 'hiya';
  to = 'me@mydomain.com';
  put to=;
run;

short=me@m
```

`to` is set with a length of 4, and SAS does not expand it to fit the new data.

### Detail

The thing to bear in mind here is how SAS works behind the scenes.

1. The `data` statement sets up an output location
2. The `set` statement adds the variables from first observation of the dataset specified to a space in memory called the PDV, inheriting lengths and data types.

PDV:

```
bill_account_number|customer_number|email_addr|e_customer_nm
===================================================================
010101             |            758|me@my.com |John Smith
```

3. The `to` statement adds another variable inheriting the characteristics of `customer_number`

PDV:

```
bill_account_number|customer_number|email_addr|e_customer_nm|to
===================================================================
010101             |            758|me@my.com |John Smith   |758
```

(`to` is either char length 3 or a numeric)

4. Subsequent `to` statements will not alter the characteristics of the variable and SAS will continue processing

PDV (if customer_number is character = TRUNCATION):

```
bill_account_number|customer_number|email_addr|e_customer_nm|to
===================================================================
010101             |            758|me@my.com |John Smith   |me@
```

PDV (if customer_number is numeric = DATA ERROR, `to` set to missing):

```
bill_account_number|customer_number|email_addr|e_customer_nm|to
===================================================================
010101             |            758|me@my.com |John Smith   |.
```

## Resolution

To resolve this issue it's probably easiest to set the length and type of `to` before your first `to` statement:

```
data analyze;
  set css_email_analysis;
  from = bill_account_number;
  length to $200;
  to = customer_number;
  output;
  ...
```

You may get messages like this, where SAS has converted data on your behalf:

> NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character
>         values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
>         27:8

N.B. it's not necessary to explicitly define the length and type of `from`, because as far as I can see, you only ever get the values for this variable from one variable in the source dataset. You could also achieve this with a rename if you don't need to keep the `bill_account_number` variable:

```
rename bill_account_number = from;
```